# Ruby Youtube Data API gem error when deleting a playlist

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

When I execute a `youtube.playlists.delete` request I am getting back

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@vidyard_dashboard/gems/google-api-      client-0.4.4/lib/google/api_client/result.rb:53:in `media_type'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@vidyard_dashboard/gems/google-api-client-0.4.4/lib/google/api_client/result.rb:57:in `data?'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@vidyard_dashboard/gems/google-api-client-0.4.4/lib/google/api_client.rb:775:in `execute!'
```

The request seems to actually go through as the playlist is deleted, but for whatever reason the the still throws an error on the way back. The basic code for the request looks like:

```
yt.client.execute!(
    :api_method => yt.youtube.playlists.delete, 
    :parameters => {:id => 'youtube_playlist_id'}
)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, or a version mismatch, in the gem/client

Comment: It certainly sounds like a issue with the client library. Please file this as a bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/issues/list